# How to deserialize following format from JSON?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to deserialize below format using NewtonSoft.json. I tried to most please provide answer as soon as possible

```
0008,0050: {
         Name: "AccessionNumber"
         Type: "Null"
         Value: null
           }-
0008,0052: {
        Name: "QueryRetrieveLevel"
        Type: "String"
        Value: "STUDY"
         }-
 0010,0010: {
       Name: "PatientName"
       Type: "String"
       Value: "KNIX"
            }-
 0010,0020: {
       Name: "PatientID"
        Type: "String"
        Value: "ozp00SjY2xG"
        }-
  0020,000d: {
       Name: "StudyInstanceUID"
        Type: "String"
       Value: "1.2.840.113619.2.176.2025.1499492.7391.1171285944.390"
              }-
    }"
```

Comment: NewtonSoft.json is not working?

Comment: Is this a `string` input? Provide a code sample of how you tried to use Json.NET please.

Comment: as stated, i think you need to provide an example of what you tried. also, the above is in no way valid json, so you'll need to show your conversion (routine?) as well and the resulting output

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get property value, try this 

`var result = GetJsonResult() as JsonResult;`

`JsonResult propertyValue = (JsonResult)result.Data.GetType().GetProperty("propertyName").GetValue(result.Data, null);`

Answer (score 0):

had you tried [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

you is prety simple and you only have to do this:

```
YourClass variableName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(jsonStringVariable);
```

in this case, if it is a list, it would be something like this:

```
List<YourClass> variableName = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<YourClass>>(jsonStringVariable);
```